# Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory - Radiant CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I installed radiant CMS as sugested on their page.

`gem install radiant`

Terminal says `successfully installed 1 gem` - sems like OK.

Then I try to create a project:

`radiant --database postgresql socialize`
Seems fine except this   `undefined local variable or method 'vars' for #<Rails::Generator::Commands::Create:0x00000001ec6ac0>`

Then I `cd /socialize` and tried `bundle install` and here I got `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

So this seems like serious error.

I know there are few questions bout that but no associated to CMS - I've tried comfortable mexican sofa ( it worked fine, but since it has no templates /layouts I switched to radiant. )

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: What version of rails Are you using .